# How to determine the true size of a font?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

A colleague of mine is submitting a research proposal to one of the UK research councils, whose guidelines stipulate a minimum font-size of 10pt.  My colleague, who is of course using LaTeX, uses the `amsart` document class with the `10pt` option (which, in fact, I think it's the default).  Looking at the `.log` file one sees that the 10pt version of the fonts are indeed being loaded.

However word has come back that the proposal falls foul of the research council's guidelines because the font-size in the PDF file that my colleague submitted is actually 9.6pt!  Alas, no information has been given as to how this font-size was determined.

#### Questions

1. When is 10pt *not* really 10pt?
2. And how can one determine the true font size of a LaTeX-generated PDF document?

Thanks in advance!

#### Added

This just in: it seems that the culprit was the default scaling of `helvetica`, which according to [the PSNFSS2e documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf) (PDF file) is smaller than 1.

This still leaves the second question.

Comment: Not the problem, but worth knowing anyway: there isn't a single width of a point, but several: see http://www.oberonplace.com/dtp/fonts/point.htm - in particular the difference between Tex and Postscript points (1/72.27 and 1/72 inch, respectively) is a real nuisance.

Comment: Thanks - I knew about the many different points, although I confess I didn't think to check whether this could be the source of the problem.  As you point out, the difference in the point size does not account for such a discrepancy in this case.

Comment: Unless you are using a phototypesetter, be kind to your reviewers and use 11pt or greater thus obviating the problem. The definitive answer would come from the rejecting research council. Also, even if you agree on what size a point is, there is significant variation in the definition of what size a fontface is.

Comment: msw: thanks -- can you point to some literature on (attempts at) a precise definition of the size of a fontface?  I'm curious.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: *precise definition of the size of a fontface* - The em-size the font designer states, the height of the tallest glyph in a font, and the vertical space Tex allocates to the text typeset in a font can all be different.  The first is the usual measure, but you can't infer it from measuring the glyphs.  This might be a good question to ask here.

Comment: I've created a broader question following on from here: How to make sense of font metrics, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/how-to-make-sense-of-font-metrics

Comment: Open pdf with inkscape, you can find the font name, weight and size via the text edit tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PDFedit](http://pdfedit.petricek.net/en/download.html) will be able tell you what the size of particular bit of text in a PDF document is.

Comment: A hint on _how_ would be great.

Comment: Open the pdf -> Click on 'Text' from top menu -> Click on 'Insert' from top menu -> A window will be opened -> Click on 'Select font from page' -> Select the text that you want to know its font -> You can see the font in the opened window

Comment: just for your info, it was not able to open by pdf of my whole thesis file built with lualatex on linux, but worked for a specially compiled chapter.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe Acrobat professional: Tools -> Advanced Editing -> Touchup text tool. Select text, right click -> Properties. Text tab, Font Size box.

Comment: Thanks.  Alas, I do not have access to this software.  I did download the Acrobat Reader (for which I have no other use in principle) since I had vague memories that it did have a way to show the fonts being used, but it only gave the names of the fonts, their encoding,... but no information on the size beyond the one gleaned from the name of the font.

Answer (score 2):

There are several definitions of the word “point,” and LaTeX itself has two different units, the `pt` and the `bp` (for “big point”).

Since you say that’s a minimum size, the easiest solution is probably to load `\documentclass[11pt]`.

With `fontspec` and a modern TeX engine, you have the option of setting `\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }` and then loading your main font with `\setmainfont[Scale = 1.042]`.  (Or 4.2% higher than whatever it’s at now.)  This should scale your main font to the size the publisher requested, and scale all the other fonts in the document to the same height.

If you’re using 8-bit fonts, many legacy font packages support a `scale=` option.

Comment: Note that with the KOMA-Script classes, you can use `bp` as a measurement directly without having to change the scaling, e.g. `\documentclass[fontsize=12bp]{scrartcl}`.

Comment: @AndrewDunning Yes, although I don’t think that this could be a simple `10bp` fix unless the point size given in the OP is a typo.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's not the problem in the original question; no doubt it was accidentally setting the `Scale` option (as I discuss more in my answer).

Comment: @AndrewDunning That’s possible. The OP doesn’t give a MCVE, which makes it harder for us to figure out what’s going on.

Answer (score 2):

Many documents include `Scale=MatchLowercase` or `Scale=MatchUppercase` as default font features with `fontspec`, which makes sense, except that this causes the package to scale the main font against the prior default  (normally Latin Modern). To check what LaTeX considers to be the font size, you can use something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
% font will be rendered at 11.02771pt with the following line removed
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

The quick fox --- \the\fontdimen6\font\relax

\end{document}
```

[image: Font size test]

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to many other questions dealing with "font size".
I wrote this simple tex file for myself. I have taken out my (pure XeTeX) formatting commands
so as to make it readable and changeable.
See the attached PDF file where the font was Libertine Roman at a nominal point size of `12.5pt`

#### Introductory material

When we speak of the point size of a  classical (i.e. engraved in metal) this is a nominal value. Each character will have a different 
combination of *height* (total distance above the base line), *depth* (total distance below the base line) and 
*width*. Similarly in `TeX` if  we define a font to have a size of `14.0 pt`
then `14.0` points is the nominal size. In `TeX` we can precisely determine the above values by looking at the
*bounding box* of a letter. We do this by placing the letter, or letters, in a hbox and the using the
command `\the` as applied to the `\ht`, `\dp` and `\wd` of the box.

Suppose that we are interested in the letter "g", which dips below the baseline. We first write:

```
\setbox0 \hbox{g}
```

and then determine the values as follows:

```
height = \the\ht0

depth =  \the\dp0

width =  \the\wd0
```

Here is the entire program:

```
\setbox0 \hbox{g}

\centerline {
height = \the\ht0
depth =  \the\dp0
width =  \the\wd0
                  }
```

We can also obtain the *maximum* range for a given nominal point size by placing the *entire alphabet* inside
a hbox:

```
\setbox1 \hbox{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\centerline {
height = \the\ht1,\qq
depth =  \the\dp1,\qq
width =  \the\wd1
                  }
```

link 1  PDF output

link 2  original TEX file (plain XeTeX, the macro commands are available
    link to macro files if desired

Comment: The links are: http://people.math.carleton.ca/~rhfischl/DO_IT_YOURSELF_TEX/font_size.pdf and http://people.math.carleton.ca/~rhfischl/DO_IT_YOURSELF_TEX/font_size.tex [I obviously did not understand the "link" function]

Answer (score 0):

You can copy fragment of the text from PDF viewer (I tried both Adobe and Foxit reader) and paste it to some text editor supporting copy / paste of formatted text (I an on Windows thus used Word). The text is normally pasted with formatting, thus font size can be seen as property of this text.

Comment: Hm, it can go wrong without notice.