# How to set font size at exactly 11 pt?

Tags: fontsize

I am trying to write a research proposal in LaTeX. To this end, I am using the package `proposal`.

The guidelines are strict, my proposal MUST be written in Arial 11 pt. My concern is the following: I have the feeling that the font size is somehow slightly smaller than 11 pt. This feeling was confirmed by comparing the same text printed out from a Word file with Arial fonts, 11 pt.

I found a question pretty similar here:
[How to determine the true size of a font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-to-determine-the-true-size-of-a-font)
 but I must say it did not suffice to fix my problem.

I have tried to look into the `.log` file, and found that line:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ua1/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.40245pt on input line 22.
```

although the first lines of the log file show that the 11 pt option was properly transmitted to the base class (through `dfgproposal` -> `proposal` -> `article`):

```
Document Class: dfgproposal 2013/02/13 v1.4 DFG Proposal
(./proposal.cls
Document Class: proposal 2013/02/13 v1.4 Project Proposal
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
```

EDIT: Alright, I found the answer myself, as I was trying to write a minimal working example (at the request of Harish Kumar). To be able to produce a document with the Arial font, I use the package uarial. What I did not know is that uarial takes an argument called "scaled":

```
\usepackage[scaled=xxx]{uarial}
```

By default, scaled is not 1.0, because Arial produces letters that are bigger than other fonts. So, simply writing

```
\usepackage[scaled=1.0]{uarial}
```

solved my problems.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? Details: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I use direct font loading from time to time `\font\myfont=cmr10 at 11pt \myfont`, but that's not exactly what you are looking for and it is not a common approach.

Comment: The notion of “Arial at 11pt” is actually not well defined. The specification should be “Arial at what a well known program thinks to be 11pt”. Which is definitely not 11pt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have the package installed but google suggests you are using

http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/fonts/urw/arial/latex/t1ua1.fd

which is

```
\ProvidesFile{t1ua1.fd}
   [2006/03/21 Fontinst v1.928 font definitions for T1/ua1.]

\expandafter\ifx\csname ua1@Scale\endcsname\relax
 \let\uaI@@Scale\@empty
\else
 \edef\uaI@@Scale{s*[\csname ua1@Scale\endcsname]}%
\fi

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{ua1}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{m}{n}{ <-> \uaI@@Scale ua1r8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{m}{it}{ <-> \uaI@@Scale ua1ri8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{b}{n}{ <-> \uaI@@Scale ua1b8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{b}{it}{ <-> \uaI@@Scale ua1bi8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * ua1/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * ua1/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * ua1/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * ua1/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ua1}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * ua1/b/sl}{}
```

which suggests that (if the package has no other options to control it) that you could turn off scaling by adding the line

```
  \expandafter\let\csname ua1@Scale\endcsname\relax
```

to your preamble, although actually you could do

```
 \expandafter\def\csname ua1@Scale\endcsname{1.00375}
```

since when the guidelines say `11pt` they will mean postscript points `bp` in TeX which are 72.27/72 bigger than TeX points.

As noted in comments you don't have to set `\ua1@Scale` explictly, there is a package option so

```
\usepackage[scaled=1.00375]{uarial}
```

Will give 11bp font size instead of the default scale of  0.95*11pt.

Comment: or just `\usepackage[scaled=1.00375]{uarial}` instead of the `0.95` default value!

Comment: Wow, I had not seen you answer... thank you, you got it ! Thanks also for the 72.27 / 72 = 1.00375 tip...

Comment: @Josef thanks, I suspect you have the package or looked at its documentation or something:-) I'll add that to the answer, obviously what you suggest is better syntax for setting that if there is a scaled option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just looked into `uarial.sty`! ;-) But i was aware of Walter's other font packages especially `psnfss`. So i had a strong suspicion. Strangely, the `scaled` option is not documented. Its value was taken from `helvet.sty`, which is used there for better font size matching with `Times`, `Palatino` and `Courier` fonts. So `uarial.sty` should work as drop in replacement for `helvet.sty`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, now i understand your comment. `uarial.sty` is not even in my `TeXLive` installation. I just followed the link you provided! ;-)