# How to avoid scaling of font?

Tags: fonts, xetex

Source:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

When checking font size with Xara Designer, it tells me that it’s actually
10.91 pt, which I don’t understand as I’m assuming that `Scale=1` explicitly
disables scaling.

Note that I’m looking for a general solution, i.e. one applicable to any font
that `\setromanfont` takes.

Just in case you think this is a duplicate: The answer to the question
[How to set font size at exactly 11 pt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167402/how-to-set-font-size-at-exactly-11-pt]) is not applicable to XeLaTeX.

Comment: The 11pt option of article chooses 10.95pt as main font size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set font size at exactly 11 pt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167402/how-to-set-font-size-at-exactly-11-pt)

Comment: @samcarter Similar problem, but different cause. The answer to the author’s question is specific to the `proposal` package, which I’m not using.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, and 10.95pt is 10.91bp.  So if Xara Designer uses bp, there is consistency.  Is the answer as simple as setting `Scale=1.00457`?

Comment: Just use `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1.00833333}` and you get a font size of exactly 11bp. It's just simple math: 72,27/72*11/10,95 = 1.00833333

Comment: @feklee The linked question is not specific to `proposal` since `proposal` itself calls `article`, so it is exactly your problem. Try the scaling factor at the end of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167404/36296, which also Benjamin stated in his comment.

Comment: Is this relevant?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315481/setting-font-size-in-xelatex