# Is there no direct, verbatim way to define a fontsize in points for a certain secondary font?

Tags: fontsize, fontspec

## The task

I’m writing my thesis in (Xe)LaTeX, using `fontspec` for font definitions. The document’s main font size is `12pt`, passed to TeX *via* a `\documentclass` option. I want to define myself an auxiliary font with `10pt` size for certain uses. Ideally, I would want to enter that size of the auxiliary directly when defining it with `\newfontfamily`.

Skim ahead to **‘the question’** section for what one could call a ‘too long, didn’t read’ summary.

## Potential solutions known to me

One thing I immediately noticed is that `\footnotesize` would scale the text to `10pt` — the correct font size that I am looking for. I employed this in two different ways as can be seen later in the MWE.

Another option is to use `fontspec`’s `SizeFeatures`, as recommended in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315484).

A third one is to [define a `\fontsize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48277) — however, that requires calculating two different values; something I think TeX should do rather than me.

Finally, one can also `Scale` the font in its defintion as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141697) recommends.

I did not find any direct ways to specify a font’s size *via* the `\newfontfamily` command in the [`fontspec` documentation on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec).

## The MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} % see also note [1]
\usepackage{mathspec} % includes fontspec
\usepackage{polyglossia} % for languages — see note [2]
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true,spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif} % my main font — see note [3].
\newfontfamily\antiquasans[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSans}  % A secondary font for demonstration
\newfontfamily\overpicfont[Mapping=tex-text, SizeFeatures={Size=10}]{LiberationSans} % defining with SizeFeatures
\newfontfamily\overpicscale[Mapping=tex-text, Scale=0.83]{LiberationSans} % defining with Scale

\newcommand\overpiccommand[1]{{\antiquasans\footnotesize #1}} % defined as an environment.

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]                            % a comparison paragraph

{\antiquasans \lipsum[1]}             % a sans-serif paragraph with 12pt

\overpiccommand{\lipsum[1]}           % the environment including \footnotesize

{\overpicfont\footnotesize\lipsum[1]} % font forced to 10pt by SizeFeatures and footnotesize

{\overpicfont\lipsum[1]}              % font forced to 10pt by SizeFeatures

{\overpicscale\lipsum[1]}             % font scaled

\lipsum[1]                            % 12pt comparison paragraph

\end{document}
```

## Rendered output

The rendered output with a document font size of `12pt` is split into two images as there was a page break.

[image: Rendered output 12pt document part 1][image: Rendered output 12pt document part 2]

From top to bottom:

- last line of standard (serif) text
- sans-serif with `\antiquasans`
- `\overpiccommand` environment, includes `\antiquasans\footnotesize`
- `\overpicfont\footnotesize` variant — includes both `FontFeatures` and `\footnotesize`. This is the paragraph split by a page break.
- using only `FontFeatures`
- using only `Scale`
- comparison text in `12pt` serif typeface.

[image: Rendered output 10pt document]

In the `10pt` document, we can compare the following paragraphs:

- last line of standard (serif) text
- sans-serif with `\antiquasans`
- `\overpiccommand` environment, includes `\antiquasans\footnotesize`
- `\overpicfont\footnotesize` variant — includes both `FontFeatures` and `\footnotesize`. Note that `\footnotesize` defines `8pt` here while the `FontFeatures` require `10pt`.
- using only `FontFeatures`

## Testing results

The first thing that I noticed was that different ways to define `10pt` in a `12pt` document led to two different line heights — see the attached images. The fonts’ (both Liberation’s and LiberationSans’) standard `12pt` line height is c. 5 mm. Using the `SizeFeature` forcing and the `Scale` factor, the line heights remained this even if the font size was smaller. Anything that included `\footnotesize` (the environment and the additional `\footnotesize` forcing) gave a line height of c. 4.2 mm consistent with the standard line height of the `10pt` document.

Therefore, using the `SizeFeatures` or `Scale` options is not an option as it results in incorrect (too large) line spacing.

Further testing with the `10pt` document revealed that `SizeFeatures` does not affect line height at all: the paragraph including `\footnotesize` and a `SizeFeatures` scaled font had a line height of c. 3 mm — consistent with `8pt` footnotes — while the font size was clearly `10pt` as requested by `SizeFeatures`.

## Conclusions

- As I stated before, I don’t want to use `\fontsize`. I want to somehow tell TeX to use a font size of `10pt` in my `12pt` document and let the engine do the required scaling.
- For the same reason, I am not happy with using `SizeFeatures`. These make the font size smaller but do not adjust the line height.
- Using a `Scale` argument also comes with that problem but also the added disadvantage that `10/12` is a nonfinite number. So rather than entering a clear `10pt`, I have to make do with some approximation. A very bad solution.
- Using an environment would probably work if I had only inline examples, but I suspect it is going to fail for the intended uses I have. However, given that the environment definition *worked,* I can most likely define myself a command that would expand to the same thing.
- The least-best option is to just append a `\footnotesize` to every occurance of `\overpicfont`.

## The question

Does some way of adding a discreet, non-variable font size option exist when defining a new font family, such that TeX automatically chooses appealing line heights and adjusts all other sizes accordingly? Something along the lines of:

```
\newfontfamily\tenpointfont[size=10pt, other options]{MyCrazyFontsName}
```

---

### Notes

[1]: I also ran a comparison run without the `12pt` option, i.e. with TeX’ standard font size of `10pt`.

[2]: For some reason, I got an error when not including `polyglossia` and a language definition, hence I left it in the document. I don’t think it’s crucial in any way, though.

[3]: I have read that `Mapping=tex-text` and `Ligatures=TeX` are identical while the latter ensures compability with LuaLaTeX. Since I am only using XeLaTeX, I did not change this when copying from my last thesis.

Comment: There is no "standard line height" for the font: this is determined by the `size12.clo` which is loaded by the `article` class and not by the font. Internally it uses `\fontsize`, and specifies both a fontsize and the leading. This is why using the builtin font changing commands work the way they do. So define your font family and then make wrappers which calculate the size correctly using `\fontsize`. The leading can be calculated to be whatever proportion of the fontsize you like.

Comment: If you also want to adjust the interline spacing, then `\footnotesize` is the correct way.

Comment: it isn't at all clear from your question what you want that is different from `\footnotesize` which selects 10pt font on 12pt baseline in the report class 12pt option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want something that is a single command. If `\overpicfont\footnotesize` is the shortest way to do this, then the answer is ‘no, there is no faster and direct way.’

Comment: you don't need to load a 10pt font just `\antiquasans\footnotesize` would be the normal way. You can of course define that to be a single command if you need it often.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, that was the idea. Because I would use it often, I hoped that there would be a single command solution without me writing an additional macro.

Comment: hard to see how _any_ proposed declaration could be simpler or require less commands to be entered than `\newcomand\foo{\antiquasans\footnotesize}` ?

Comment: You don't need an additional macro, just a different one, surely? `\DeclareRobustCommand\overpicfont{\antiquasans\footnotesize}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main misunderstanding appears to be

> As I stated before, I don’t want to use \fontsize. I want to somehow tell TeX to use a font size of 10pt in my 12pt document and let the engine do the required scaling.

The font itself (and the `fontspec` font loading commands) do not specify the baseline spacing. The baseline spacing needs to be specified in the document class (or adjusted in the preamble). The class needs to specify the line spacing along with all other spacing, this is why the `\fontsize` command takes two arguments, it is up to the document designer to specify the baseline for each font size.

So the natural way to specify the font to be used at 10pt on a 12pt baseline would be `\antiquasans\footnotesize` it would in theory be possible to drop to a slightly lower level and avoid selecting the intermediate font just as `\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{it}\selectfont`  avoids doing two `\selectfont` that would be implied by `\bfseries\itshape` so directly selecting the bold italic without first selecting bold or italic, however the gains compared to the rest of the work done in loading an opentype font are unlikely to be measurable.