# How to create PDF output in exactly 11pt font?

Tags: fonts

I am writing a grant proposal in LaTeX which has to be in 11pt sans-serif font. Upon submitting the final PDF version to my grants office, they have informed that Adobe Acrobat reports the font size as 10.91pt. Apparently this will not be accepted by the funding body.

**How can I use LaTeX to create a document which Adobe Acrobat will report to be in exactly 11pt font?**

My document looks something like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Here is my excellent grant proposal.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is relevant, but does not supply a solution to the problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-to-determine-the-true-size-of-a-font

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point

Comment: Use `fontsize`.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat has its own (incorrect) idea about font sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `anyfontsize` package to select a choice font size. In TeX, `1pt=1/72.27in` while in Adobe and most contemporary applications, `1pt=1/72in`. (See: [Why does a TeX point differ from a Desktop Publishing point?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point)) If you want the latter measurement in TeX, use units of `bp`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \fontsize{11bp}{13.2bp}\selectfont%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like it's working well for me. My grants office is happy, so I'm happy. Thanks!